# Rendering condition vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I created a login page,
where I made the conditions. if not logged in displays NAVBAR A
if login is successful displays NAVBAR B. In the login process I created a local storgare storage in which a token is stored. I ask why is mounted late rendering?
when the user is logged in it should render navbar B, it works if it is refreshed first

my code app.vue

```
<v-main>
     <NavA v-if="token==='' "/> //if not login
     <NavB v-if="token!='' "/> // if login success
      <router-view />
</v-main>

data: () => ({
    drawer: true,
    token: '',
  }),

  mounted () {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  },
```

Comment: give `token: null` and `<NavA v-if="token == null "/>`

Answer (score 1):

change "mounted" to "created", maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**You should always use `if-else` condition.**

```
<v-main>
   <NavA v-if="token == null "/> //if not login
   <NavB v-else /> // else login success
   <router-view />
</v-main>

data: () => ({
  drawer: true,
  token: null,
}),

mounted () {
   this.token = localStorage.getItem('token')
},
```

This is working for me. See in Sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-aryabhata-pl2k4?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: For this it works, but when the rendering doesn't work, it must be refreshed first

Answer (score 0):

You can try using beforeMount hook instead of using the mounted hook.